# Show that $H(v, y) = \frac{v^2}{2} - F(y)$ is a first integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, runge-kutta-methods, hamilton-equations

$H(v, y) = \frac{v^2}{2} - F(y)$ is a hamiltonian of $y' = v, v' = f(y)$

Linear first integrals are of the form $I(x) = b^Tx + c$ where $b \in ℝ^d $ and $ c \in ℝ$

Quadratic first integrals are of the form $I(x) = x^TMx+b^Tx+c$ where $M \in ℝ^{d,d}$, $b \in ℝ^d $ and $ c \in ℝ$

I am unsure how to get the function $H(v,y)$ in either form or somehow else show it is indeed a first integral

Could someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed your ODE is the Hamiltonian system
$$
\dot y = H_v=v\\
\dot v = -H_y=F'(y)
$$
For any Hamiltonian system you have along solutions
$$
\frac{d}{dt}H(v(t),y(t))=H_v\dot v+H_y\dot y=0
$$
so that the Hamiltonian function is a first integral.

Comment: cheers mate, i appreciate the help